# JavaFX LineChart is clipping the series drawing

Tags: javafx, linechart

Bug or feature? When the value is at 0 (min) or 1 (max), the series appears to be clipped. I expect the red layer to be in front and not clipped.

[image: series clipped at min and max]

Setting min,max to -0.1,1.1 avoids the clipping but make a mess.

[image: min and max tweaked]

I can't think of anything else to try other than tweaking the background and the padding, to no effect.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.chart.*;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class LineChartClipping extends Application {

  LineChart makeRoot() {
    NumberAxis xAxis = new NumberAxis();
    NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis(0, 1, 1); // (-0.1, 1.1, 1);
    var chart = new LineChart(xAxis, yAxis);
    var series = new LineChart.Series<>();
    chart.getData().add(series);
    double x = 0;
    for (var value : new double[]{0.5, 0, 1.0}) {
      series.getData().add(new LineChart.Data<>(x, value));  x += 2;
      series.getData().add(new LineChart.Data<>(x, value));
    }
    return chart;
  }

  @Override
  public void start(Stage stage) {
    stage.setScene(new Scene(makeRoot(), 180, 120));
    stage.show();
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) { launch(args); }
}
```

In my use case, I do

```
    chart.setCreateSymbols(false);
    xAxis.setTickMarkVisible(false);
    xAxis.setMinorTickVisible(false);
    xAxis.setTickLabelsVisible(false);
```

so the horizontals at min/max look like this:

[image]

- macOS Catalina, Retina iMac (HiDPI)
- JavaFX 15.0.1, Java 15.0.1

Comment: [mcve] please..

Comment: It is a reproducible example, cut down significantly from the actual code. I don't know what else I could remove that would make it materially simpler.

Comment: don't see any code _here_ .. please read the referenced help page and act accordingly

Comment: @kleopatra I tried to post with minimal code here. SO wouldn't allow it.

Comment: strip it down, just a plain chart (move only on to a custom chart once this is solved) with your configuration and data .. that's a handlful of lines and shouldn't be too much.

Comment: @kleopatra thanks :)

Comment: hmm ... the clip is set in XYChart to exactly the size of the inner plot area (that is inside the axis), no idea how to change that (without either going extremely dirty like resetting it or roll your own entirely). Actually, I don't quite see what you expect: without the clip, the line would smear over the axis f.i. I would go with a slight adjustment of the axis range: increase the range, remove all the clutter lines, adjust the ticks to the real boundaries ..

Comment: Seems to me that there should be an option not to clip. I've filed a bug report.

Comment: okay, but still don't understand what exactly you want: without clip the lines and the symbols will overlay the ticks - doesn't look great, either ..

Comment: I think it looks better, especially in my use case, which I appended to the question.

Answer (score -1):

You'll need to make your charts range slightly more than 0 to 1, something like -0.1 to 1.1. The chart stops exactly at 0 and 1, and since the line has some thickness it clips at the edges.